# How to interpret lifetime score

Tags: history, world-championship

I can not understand what the following numbers mean:

> Gligorić had the following record against the world champions he
>   played against: Max Euwe +2 -0 =5, Mikhail Botvinnik +2 −2 =6, Vasily
>   Smyslov +6 −8 =28, Tigran Petrosian +8 −11 =19, Mikhail Tal +2 −10
>   =22, Boris Spassky +0 −6 =16, Bobby Fischer +4 −7 =8, Anatoly Karpov +0 −4 =6 and Garry Kasparov +0 −3 =0.

I took them from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetozar_Gligori%C4%87#Lifetime_scores_against_world_champions). I do understand that it tracks statistics against a particular opponent in all games, but what is this strange mathematics mean: **+8 −11 =19**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but what is this strange mathematics mean: +8 −11 =19?

This is not mathematical notation. The three symbols are not there so you can add or subtract numbers. They mean the following:

- `+` is the number of victories;
- `-` is the number of defeats;
- `=` is the number of draws player achieved against an opponent;

So in the following example:

> Gligorić had the following record against the world champions he played against: Max Euwe +2 -0 =5

Gligoric had 2 victories, no defeats and five draws against Max Euwe.

Against Fisher he had +4 -7 =8, meaning he won 4 games against him, lost 7 and drew 8.

Comment: why cw? seems very unnecessarily humble of you

Answer (score 5):

**+8 -11 =19** means: **Won 8, lost 11 and drew 19**